# Minimum Alignment Requirements for a Machine

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I am reading a book on compiler design and implementation. In the part about storage management the author writes a function to allocate memory. He wants the function to be suitably aligned for any type. He claims that the size of the union below is the minimum alignment on the host machine. I don't quite understand what that means. From the book: "... its fields are those that are most likely to have the strictest alignment requirements."

```
union align {
    long l;
    char *p;
    double d;
    int (*f) (void);
};
```

Could somebody explain what 'strictest alignment requirements' means and how does this give the minimum alignment on the host machine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alignment of a union is chosen to be the same as the alignment of the member with the greatest alignment requirements. Its size chosen to be as big as the biggest member, plus some additional padding at the end to ensure that the alignment doesn't break when it is laid out sequentially in an array.

So in that sense, `union align` will have the same alignment as either `l`, `p`, `d` or `f` (whichever has the greatest alignment requirements).

For example, if the `f` member which is of type `int (*)(void)` has an alignment requirement of `8`, the whole union will be aligned on an 8-byte boundary, even if `long` requires only `4`.

I am not quite certain whether the standard guarantees that the greatest alignment requirement from these 4 types will be the "minimum alignment on the host machine". It may be just a good exercise in order to understand the way in which the compiler works with regard to storage management.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a machine that, due to memory bus limitations, can read 16-bit values only from even addresses.

A 16-bit value on such a machine would have an "alignment requirement" of 2.

Do **not** rely on `union` trickery. Since C11, there are:

- [`max_align_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t) which is synonymous to the largest (standard) scalar type for a platform(1), i.e. a type with the alignment as served by `malloc()`.
- [`_Alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof), which gives the alignment requirements for a given type.
- [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas), which allows to modify the alignment of types.

(1): The largest such type would *usually* be `long double`, a type suspiciously absent from your book's example...

Note that a compiler might support "extension" types which require special handling. For example, having a 256-byte SSE data type, but having `malloc()` "only" do 128-byte alignment.